# C++ file handle

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to implement a file handle class similar to the one in Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ page. (Scroll to ["Why doesn't C++ provide a 'finally' construct"](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#renew).) Unlike his example, however, I want to use C++ file streams instead of a `FILE*`.

Right now, I am considering creating a `FileHandleBase` class, or something similarly named, and two derived classes—one for input files and one for output files. Below is the implementation I wrote as a proof-of-concept; keep in mind that it is *very* simple and unfinished.

```cpp
class FileHandle {
public:
    FileHandle(const char* fn, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out) {
        file.open(fn, mode);
        // Check to make sure file is open
    }
    FileHandle(const string &fn, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out) {
        file.open(fn, mode);
        // Check to make sure file is open
    }
    ~FileHandle() {
        file.close();
    }
private:
    fstream file;
};
```

I would like to know if this is a viable way of making a file handle, that is, whether my inheritance idea is good. I also want to know the best way to deal with the `ios_base::openmode` parameter because the C++ reference page for `std::ifstream` says this:

> Note that even though ifstream is an input stream, its internal filebuf object may be set to also support output operations.

In what cases would an `ifstream` be used for output operations, and, similarly, when would an `of stream` be used for input operations; and should I restrict the options for the `ios_base::openmode` parameter for my file handle class(es)? That way my input file handle would only handle input operations, and the output version would only handle output operations.

Comment: Would it be fine to just use a generic `fstream` to eliminate the additional complexity surrounding the `std::ios_base::openmode` parameter and derived classes?

Comment: `std::fstream`'s destructor already closes the file.  You don't need a wrapper.  What you're describing is exactly `std::fstream`, `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`.

Comment: It would appear I am D-U-M dumb. Thank you for pointing out the obvious I was too blind to see. I imagine I would only want this kind of wrapper for a `FILE*`, as implemented in Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ page.

Comment: Right, you only need that sort of RAII guard for resources that don't clean themselves up, like `FILE*`s (`std::fstream`), dynamically-allocated memory (`std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`) or various OS-specific handles (Windows `HANDLE`s or POSIX file descriptors; no standard-library provided manager class).

Comment: Standard fstreams are already file handles. There is no need to create a handle of a handle.

Answer (score 0):

> In what cases would an `ifstream` be used for output operations, and, similarly, when would an `ofstream` be used for input operations

You would open an output file stream with an `std::ios_base::in` openmode and vice-versa for an input file stream if you would still like to perform those associated operations using the internal `std::filebuf` object, which is accessible by `stream->rdbuf()`. Note that the streams `std::ofstream` and `std::ifstream` will still be able to perform output and input respectively even if they are opened with opposite openmodes.

```c++
int main() {
    std::ofstream stream("test.txt");
    stream << "Hello" << std::flush;
    stream.close();
    stream.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::in);
    char buffer[SIZE] = {};
    stream.rdbuf()->sgetn(buffer, SIZE);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```